# How can I write the equation of this graph?

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

I have this simple graph : 
[image]

I want to write this graph in this form :

f(t)= {1, if .... and 2, if ...}
I can't fill these spaces, I can't come to a solution for this no matter how I try. Can you write the equation of this graph? Thanks.

Comment: Is the width of the "humps" evenly spaced?  The picture looks like they are all the same width, but the labelling of the $x$-axis suggests they are not.

Comment: That's not the graph of a function. It's a one-many relation.

Comment: @TravisJ yes they are evenly spaced.

Answer (score 1):

Use some version of $$\lfloor \sin(a \cdot t+b)+c \rfloor$$
Where $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is the floor function and a,b, and c are constants. You can integrate this piecewise to find the area under the graph. By the way, your graph is referred to as a square wave.